# show hide jquery table rows for imported xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, show-hide

I was trying to do the following, but stuck somewhere at the point where to show hide table row elements. What I did is importing xml to html through jquery library as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.xml", 
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {  
   $(xml).find('event').each(function(){    
    var Col0 = $(this).find('title').text();
    var Col1 = $(this).find('country').text();
    var Col2 = $(this).find('date').text();
    var Col3 = $(this).find('time').text();
    var Col4 = $(this).find('course').text();
    var Col5 = $(this).find('topic').text();
    var Col6 = $(this).find('pre-course').text();
    $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>'+Col0+'</th><td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td><td>'+Col3+'</td><td>'+Col4+'</td><td>'+Col5+'</td><td>'+Col6+'</td>').appendTo('#test');
   });
  }
 });
});
```

I added some html to make things work like this:

```
     <table id="test">
       <tr><td></td><th>country</th>
        <th>Date</th><th>time</th>
         <th>course</th><th>topic</th>
          <th>pre-course</th></tr>
     </table>
```

Everything at this point is working well and the table is fully displayed. The issue comes up when I try to use the following java code to hide all table rows expect the first 5 rows.

```
$(function() {
/* initial variables */
var numRows = $('#test').find('tr').length;
var SHOWN = 5;
var MORE = 5;

/* get how many more can be shown */
var getNumMore = function(ns) {
    var more = MORE;
    var leftOver = numRows - ns;
    if((leftOver) < more) {
        more = leftOver;
    }
    return more;
}
/* how many are shown */
var getInitialNumShown = function() {
    var shown = SHOWN;
    if(numRows < shown) {
        shown = numRows;
    }
    return shown;
}
/* set how many are initially shown */
var numShown = getInitialNumShown();

/* set the numMore if less than 20 */
var numMore = getNumMore(numShown);

/* set more html */
if(numMore > 0) {
    var more_html = '<p><button id="more">Show <span style="font-weight: bold;">' + numMore + '</span> More...</button></p>';
    $('#test').find('tr:gt(' + (numShown - 1) + ')').hide().end().after(more_html);
}
$('#more').click(function(){
    /* determine how much more we should update */
    numMore = getNumMore(numShown);
    /* update num shown */
    numShown = numShown + numMore;
    $('#test').find('tr:lt('+numShown+')').show();

    /* determine if to show more and how much left over */
    numMore = getNumMore(numShown);
    if(numMore > 0) {
        $('#more span').html(numMore);
    }
    else {
        $('#more').remove();
    }
});

});
```

when I execute the code, the show hide javascript get neglected and all table rows elements show up...

any idea how to display on the first 5 rows only and then whenever I click show more, more 5 elements show up and so on!!

Thanks

Comment: the basic problem I'm seeing is your second script related to finding numRows is executing before the table is loaded with the ajax data

Comment: ok, this is what I thought as well. however, I'm not sure how to fix that!! any idea?? Thanks

Comment: Call this function after you get all the results of the ajax call (add it to the success function)

Comment: @ShaiAharoni, thanks for the comments, but can you illustrate how! I'm just a beginner....

Comment: Wrap all your last JS code (that starts with $(function() {
/* initial variables */) into a function like this: function initalizeTable() {...all your code ..} and call this function after the line $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>'+Col0...

Comment: when I do that, no results show up, only empty table

Comment: I added this code after the line $('<tr>.... function initalizeTable(); should that be in a specific place??

Comment: ok, at last now it works great. However, the show more button shows up as multiple buttons one after another.... it is supposed to be only one button not many... any idea??